# Flask-Admin GeoAlchemy2 example doesn't show a map

Tags: mapbox, flask-admin, geoalchemy2

I'm trying to run this example about how to use Flask-Admin displaying maps: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/geo_alchemy.

In README.rst, there's this instruction:

6. You will notice that the maps are not rendered. To see them, you will have to register for a free account at Mapbox and set the MAPBOX_MAP_ID and MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN config variables accordingly.

I already have a valid MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN, and I went to MapBox to look for a MAPBOX_MAP_ID. There I read that MAP_ID was deprecated, and now I'll have to obtain a tileset ID, and it's described as a label composed by ***<my_mapbox_user_name>.the_tileset_ID*** itself.

So I located the code as they described in the instructions (in my case, mapbox-streets-v8) and fulfilled the config.py parameters:

```
MAPBOX_MAP_ID = '<my_mapbox_user_name>.mapbox-streets-v8'
MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'pk.eyJ1...'
```

However, I couldn't see any map displayed or any error message.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small bug in file Lib\site-packages\flask_admin\static\admin\js\form.js. The original URL generated to get a tile is:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/<MAPBOX_MAP_ID parameter>/tiles/12/2258/2457?access_token=<MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN parameter>
```

However, the correct one is:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/<MAPBOX_MAP_ID parameter>/tiles/12/2258/2457?access_token=<MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN parameter>
```

That is, I had to remove the ***mapbox*** word from the URL.

To do that I made some changes in form.js file:

```
      //var mapboxUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/'+window.MAPBOX_MAP_ID+'/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token='+window.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
      var mapboxUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/'+window.MAPBOX_MAP_ID+'/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token='+window.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Then, it's working now:

[image]